# Product of two functions that are not in $ L^1(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is it true that if two functions are not $ L^1$ functions, then their product is not a $ L^1$ function? How can we prove it?

Comment: Hint: Similar question... if $f(x),g(x)$ are functions; is it true that if $\sup_x f(x)>C$ and $\sup_x g(x)>C$ for some constant $C$, then $\sup_x f(x)g(x) > C$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Let $\theta(x)=\cases{1 \quad x>0\\0\quad x\leq0}$

we have $\int dx\, \theta(\pm x)=\infty$, but $\theta(x)\theta(-x)=0$ which is clearly $L^1$

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Consider $f(x)=0$ if $x < 1$ and $f(x)=1/x$ if $x\geq 1$. Then $f \not \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $f^2 \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I suggest $\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ instead, smother, no issue at $0$ and same asymptotic behaviour $\frac 1x$ vs $\frac 1{x^2}$ at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}1_{[1,+\infty)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}1_{[1,+\infty)}$

$f,g$ are not in $L^1$  but $fg$ is.